# Utilizar mais de um modelo na View - C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho duas tabelas no meu banco: `Celular` e `Marca`. Para cadastrar um celular, preciso selecionar uma marca para ele, ou seja, dois *models* em uma *view*.
Como que eu faço para fazer com que dois *Models* sejam acessados na mesma *view*?

**CelularController**

```
public class MarcaCelularViewModel
{
    public List<Celular> celulares { get; set; }
    public List<Marca> marcas { get; set; }
}

public class CelularController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MarcasDAO mDAO = new MarcasDAO();
        CelularDAO cDAO = new CelularDAO();
        List<Celular> lista_celular = new List<Celular>();
        lista_celular = cDAO.getCelular();
        List<Marca> lista_marcas = new List<Marca>();
        lista_marcas = mDAO.getMarcas();
        var model = new MarcaCelularViewModel { celulares = lista_celular, marcas = lista_marcas };  
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View na seção de cadastro de celular**

```
<form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nomeCelular">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" name="nomeCelular" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="modeloCelular">Modelo</label>
                <input type="text" name="modeloCelular" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="idMarca">Marca</label>
                <select name="idMarca" class="form-control">
                    <option selected value="">---</option>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        ...Preenche com as marcas cadastradas no banco
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Adicionar Celular</button>
        </form>
```

**View na parte da tabela de celulares cadastrados**

```
 <table class="table table-hover" style="background-color:#ffffff; border-radius:10px;">
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Modelo</th>
            <th>Marca</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.idCelular)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.nomeCelular)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.modeloCelular)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.idMarca)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Vi sobre colocar o `@model` no começo do index, mas sei que isso funciona para caso seja um modelo, para vários não tenho a menor ideia como devo declarar.

Answer (score 2):

> Para cadastrar um celular, preciso selecionar uma marca para ele, ou seja, dois *models* em uma *view*.

Errado. Se o `Celular` pertence a uma `Marca`, ou seja:

```
public class Celular
{
    [Key]
    public int CelularId { get; set; }
    public int MarcaId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Marca Marca { get; set; } 
}
```

Você envia apenas `Celular` para a *View*, com uma seleção do tipo `Marca` em *ViewBag*. Estou supondo que você está usando (errado) o Entity Framework:

```
public class CelularController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Não precisa nada disso aqui, então comentei tudo.
        // MarcasDAO mDAO = new MarcasDAO();
        // CelularDAO cDAO = new CelularDAO();
        // List<Celular> lista_celular = new List<Celular>();
        // lista_celular = cDAO.getCelular();
        // List<Marca> lista_marcas = new List<Marca>();
        // lista_marcas = mDAO.getMarcas();
        // var model = new MarcaCelularViewModel { celulares = lista_celular, marcas = lista_marcas };
        var model = contexto.Celulares
                            .Include(c => c.Marca)
                            .ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

*View*:

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="background-color:#ffffff; border-radius:10px;">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Modelo</th>
        <th>Marca</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.idCelular)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.nomeCelular)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.modeloCelular)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.Marca.Nome)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Cadastro é outra coisa completamente diferente:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Marcas = contexto.Marcas.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

*View*:

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.Celular
@using SeuProjeto.Models

<!-- form method="post" -->
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nomeCelular">Nome</label>
            <!-- input type="text" name="nomeCelular" class="form-control" required /-->
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.nomeCelular, new { htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="modeloCelular">Modelo</label>
            <!-- input type="text" name="modeloCelular" class="form-control" required /-->
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.modeloCelular, new { htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" } }
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="idMarca">Marca</label>
            <!-- select name="idMarca" class="form-control">
                ...
            </select -->
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idMarca, ((IEnumerable<Marca>)ViewBag.Marcas).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
                Text = option.Nome,
                Value = option.idMarca.ToString()
            }), "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Adicionar Celular</button>
    <!-- /form -->
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você já tem uma classe de modelo que é uma composição, ou seja, contém marcas e celulares. Esse é o único modelo que você precisa.

Se você quiser que o usuário selecione em tela uma marca e um celular específicos, você precisa adicionar mais duas propriedades:

```
public class MarcaCelularViewModel {
    public List<Marca> marcas { get; set; }
    public List<Celular> celulares { get; set; }

    public Marca marcaSelecionada { get; set; }
    public Celular celularSelecionado { get; set; }
}
```

Em uma página qualquer (supondo que suas classes tenham propriedades chamadas "id" e "descricao"):

```
@model MarcaCelularViewModel
<!-- o código abaixo deve vir dentro de um formulário -->
@Html.DropDownForListFor(m => m.marcaSelecionada, new SelectList(m.marcas, "id", "descricao"))
@Html.DropDownForListFor(m => m.celularSelecionado, new SelectList(m.celulares, "id", "descricao"))
```

Quando a tela for montada você terá dois selects, um para escolher marca e o outro para escolher celular. Quando o usuário postar a página, você saberá quais foram as escolhas do usuário através das propriedades sugeridas para o seu modelo.